# The Moment in a Fluid is of order $V^{3/4}$ if $V$ is very small

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In Batchelor's *Introduction to Fluid Dynamics*, the following statement is proposed:

> The total moment about O exerted on the fluid element by the body forces is clearly of order $V^{3/4}$ when $V$ is small, and so too is the rate of change of the angular momentum of the fluid instantaneously in $V$.

I find myself unable to grasp the reasoning behind this statement. I'm not sure where to even start. Any hint in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Body force is proportional to mass of body (think of gravity force for example), which means it is proportional to volume of body, $V$. Moment about body's center of mass is proportional to $r\times$ body mass, in which $r$ is characteristic length of the body (for a sphere it would be radius); this moment is then proportional to $rV$. But volume of the body $V~\alpha~ r^3$ (for a sphere $V=4\pi r^3/3$) and hence moment on the body is proportional to $V^{4/3}$.

Comment: Silly me! I was doing a sort of dimensional analysis and got a "proportionality" to $l^2$. I was looking at it in a completely different way. Thank you for clarifying!